# Reading from local file WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to read a text file that I have included with the project folder itself in a separate folder. I am trying to read this text file and then add each line to a list, each line as a separate item in the list, then I am looking to bind it to a listbox and each listbox item (each line previously) would be a hyperlink in the listbox. It's been very frustrating since the app just freezes every single time as soon as the code starts executing at runtime. What could be the problem?

I tried searching here a lot. I tried several of the similar problems' solutions but no use.

Code:

```
public partial class Page2 : PhoneApplicationPage
   {
       public Page2()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           // Will contain the names of malls added through a text file

           List<string> Mall_List = new List<string>();

           using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/Mall_List/Mall_List.txt"))
           {
                   while(reader.Peek() >= 0)
                   {
                       Mall_List.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                   }

                   reader.Close();
           }

               Malllist.ItemsSource = Mall_List;
        }

   }
```

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox Height="426" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="Malllist" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <HyperlinkButton Name="MallNameLinkButton"
                                         Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just reading from "local file",

```
       using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/Mall_List/Mall_List.txt"))
```

you should know WP7 has Isolated Storage, for every app.
Please make sure you are familiar with it by reading following article:

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage

More precisely, reading files is described in following article:

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files

Comment: I did, I tried with isolated storage. In fact, I ran all those sample programs without any editing too. It still raises an exception on isolated storage. First, when checking if the file exists and if I comment that block out, it raises the exception on the next line that has IsolatedStorage in it. I have been using those links you gave whilst attempting.

Comment: Just a simple question. Did you put that file in the isolated storage?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I used working code in tutorials but same thing.